# How can I plot a histogram on rotated axis in projection space (LDA)

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot, linear-discriminant

I used the mean separation criterion (find parameter w that maximizes distance between class means) as well as Fisher LDA to find a nice line to separate two linearly separable classes. Then I plotted the histogram. As you can see there is a lot of overlap. Now I want to project the points on a line (parallel to the connection line between the class means) and plot a histogram on top of this line ([Reproduce Fisher linear discriminant figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844198/reproduce-fisher-linear-discriminant-figure)). Somebody did it in Matlab but I dont have any idea how to translate this into python.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets

# set seed
np.random.seed(8)
X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=2, n_features=2, center_box=(0, 10))

# Mean separation vector
mu1 = np.mean(X[y == 0], axis=0)
mu2 = np.mean(X[y == 1], axis=0)
w = (mu2 - mu1) / np.linalg.norm(mu2 - mu1)

# Plot the mean separation vector with equivalent axis ticks
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.xlim(0, 15)
plt.ylim(0, 15)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 15, 1))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 15, 1))
plt.grid()
plt.scatter(X[:, 0][y == 0], X[:, 1][y == 0], label='Class 1')
plt.scatter(X[:, 0][y == 1], X[:, 1][y == 1], label='Class 2')
plt.plot(mu1[0], mu1[1], 'X', color='red', markersize=10, label='Mean of class 1')
plt.plot(mu2[0], mu2[1], 'X', color='red', markersize=10, label='Mean of class 2')
plt.legend()
plt.plot([mu1[0], mu2[0]], [mu1[1], mu2[1]], 'k--')
plt.arrow((mu1[0] + mu2[0]) / 2, (mu1[1] + mu2[1]) / 2, w[1], -w[0], head_width=0.3, head_length=0.3, fc='k', ec='k')
# histogram of the original data
plt.hist(X[:, 0][y == 0], bins=10, alpha=0.5, label='Class 1')
plt.hist(X[:, 0][y == 1], bins=10, alpha=0.5, label='Class 2')
plt.legend()

# Project the data on the mean separation vector
X_proj = np.dot(X, w)
```